# Is Bot Framework slow with Emulator?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I just created my first bot to echo what user input and I tested with Bot Framework Emulator.

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(opts.connector, function (session) {
   session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
});
```

However, it takes four seconds to reply.

```
[21:53:59] -> POST 202 [message] hi 
[21:53:59] <- GET 200 getConversationData 
[21:54:00] <- GET 200 getUserData 
[21:54:00] <- GET 200 getPrivateConversationData 
[21:54:01] <- POST 200 setPrivateConversationData 
[21:54:02] <- POST 200 Reply[message] You said: hi 
[21:54:03] <- POST 200 Reply[event] Debug Event
```

May I know why it takes so long time to echo and is there any solution or setting to help with?
Thanks.

Comment: This does not seem like out of the ordinary behavior in the emulator.

Comment: Are you using a custom StateClient implementation?  Are you testing with the emulator against a locally hosted bot, or a published bot?

Comment: No, I didn't use custom StateClient implementation and the connector is builder.ChatConnector now. I am testing with local hosted bot.